# Freeform : page doesn't reload after form is submited

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have a FreeForm form. On a first server everything worked just fine and since I moved the website to another server (and domain) the form doesn't reload the page on submit. It only send the form on my email but that's it. So I tried to put a return parameter but it doesn't redirect on it...

Is there a specific PHP server parameter to activate or disable to make it work ?

Thanks in advance

Versions used : FreeForm 4.1.8 / EE 2.8.1

Comment: Are you submitting the form via AJAX?

Comment: Absolutely. With the AJAX Validation script described in Solspace docs.

Comment: OK, so I'd check your javascript console and HTTP request response in Chrome to see errors and/or what is being returned by the request.